# How to dynamically get the path to the image from the worpress media library by ego ID?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a variable that contains the id of a certain image from the wordpress media library. This variable is dynamic, depending on certain actions of the user, this id changes and the variable changes accordingly. But I don't know how to start from this id and get the path to this image in the same dynamic way with the change of ID. Tell me a way to implement it

I already tried to get the image object using wp.media and fetch request and it works, but the fetch request stopped working after a while and get error 400 "Bad Request", and on mobile devices it didn't work at all:

```
imageURL = wp.media.attachment(imageID);
imageURL.fetch({});
```

Comment: _"but the fetch request stopped working after a while"_ - that is way too vague for anyone here to be able to help with; try the server-side way perhaps then, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/